# Change MastersDoctoralThesis template Latex to APA bibliography style

Tags: latex, citations

Originally the code for the bibliography in the MastersDoctoralThesis template is like this:
`\usepackage[backend=bibtex, style=authoryear, natbib=true]{biblatex}`
`\addbibresource{example.bib}`

Now I want to change this to an apa citation style. I tried a couple of things, for example:
`\usepackage[backend=biber, style=apa, autocite=inline]{biblatex}`
`\addbibresource{example.bib}`

The new code runs, but doesn't give me the results that I wish to have (citation in text is bold, and reference list is not included anymore). Moreover, it gives me the following message:

```
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2017)
The top-level auxiliary file: main.aux
A level-1 auxiliary file: Chapters/Chapter1.aux
A level-1 auxiliary file: Chapters/Chapter2.aux
A level-1 auxiliary file: Chapters/Chapter3.aux
A level-1 auxiliary file: Chapters/Chapter4.aux
A level-1 auxiliary file: Appendices/AppendixA.aux
I found no \citation commands---while reading file main.aux
I found no \bibdata command---while reading file main.aux
I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file main.aux
(There were 3 error messages)
```

Can anyone help me with finding a sollution for using the apa citation style in the MastersDoctoralThesis template? That would help me a lot!

Answer (score 1):

By `backend=biber` you are telling package `biblatex` that `biber` will be used to process the bibliography database. You have to cghange it in the preferences of your editor.

See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154751/biblatex-with-biber-configuring-my-editor-to-avoid-undefined-citations

You can also have a look at https://github.com/johannesbottcher/MDT-Quick-Manual

Or, just stay with BibTeX to sort the references, though `biber` has more features.